# difference between I wish and I hope

Tags: grammar

I was watching a talent show. One of the contestants copied a judge in a horrible voice. The judge being sulky, in a lighter mood though, said to him:

---

I hope you lose your voice.

---

Apparently it seems to be her wish that he loses his voice. Why didn’t she say:

---

I wish you lost your voice.

---

How would we differentiate between:
i.  I hope you do  this.
ii. I wish you did this.

Answer (score -1):

There is not much difference, they both intend the same end result. 
The only slight difference I know off is that "I wish" implies some form of supernatural help (see for example "to wish upon a star" or the genie from Aladdin) and "I hope" is more an expectation of natural processes, e.g. losing your voice by yelling too loud.

So in this case "I wish you lose our voice" would mean "I want the genie from Aladdin to take your voice away" which is a lot harsher than "I would like it if you did something stupid and can't talke for a bit"